# Are UserDefaults deletes when switching to a new iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, userdefaults, appstorage

When I switch from an iPhone to a new one and I choose to transfer all data from the old to the new one will this also transfer all User Defaults my app has stored?

Comment: It is getting downvoted/voted closed because it comes across as a hardware question vs a programming question. take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 
Also, look at [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html)

Comment: `UserDefaults` and the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` are for small things. You should not store anything important in them. Storage is limited and can be lost/corrupted easily.

Comment: If you restore from a backup of your old device onto your new one, your UserDefaults will be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Neither UserDefaults or Keychain will be deleted and you need to handle such cases gracefully

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a reputable source and explanation. Given the current disagreement and lack of consensus on in the comments on this post, your answer does not provide a definitive conclusion for the original poster.